# Why does the Author Claim $a_{1,1} = -1$ in this Double Summation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, summation

I'm currently reading about Sequences and Series in Understanding Analysis (*Stephen Abbott*). I'm, however, stuck on this page - trying to understand how does the author get $-1$ in the first slot in this array.

I understand that,
$$1/2^{i-j} = \frac{1}{2^{i-j}},$$

and from there it follows that for $i, j = 1$ we have:

$$a_{1,1} = \frac{1}{2^{1 - 1}} = \frac{1}{1} = 1.$$

I don't understand where the author gets the $-1$ from.

[image]

Comment: Read the statement again. $a_{ij}=-1$ when $i=j$ and $a_{ij}=1/2^{j-i}$ if $j>i$, by definition.

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing this out - I think I need some rest since I missed such an obvious thing.

Answer (score 1):

The $a_{1,1} = -1$ is because it is defined that way.  This example shows that the double sum
$$
\sum_{i,j=1}^\infty a_{i,j}
$$
is not well defined.  We would expect it to be equal to both of these iterated sums:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{i,j} = \sum_{i=1}^\infty 0 = 0
$$
and
$$
\sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{i,j} =
\sum_{j=1}^\infty (-2^{j-1}) = -2
$$